# Rails default server logs along with json logstash logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logstash

I am working on Rails app. I installed `logstash` and with help of gem `logstash-logger` I am able to get json logs output to a file `log/logstash_#{Rails.env}.log`

But along with this I want to have previous default server logs too in a separate file `log/{Rails.env}.log`.

Is it possible to do it? If yes then how?

Answer (score 0):

`logstash-logger` overrides `Rails.logger` in it's railtie.

Try adding an initializer with:

```
Rails.logger.extend(
  ActiveSupport::Logger.broadcast(
    Logger.new(Rails.root.join("log/#{Rails.env}.log"))
  )
)
```

(this should run after logstash has been initialized)

For familiar rails logger you may want to use something like

```
ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(
  ActiveSupport::Logger.new(output_filename_here).tap{|l|
    l.formatter = Rails.application.config.log_formatter
  }
)
```

instead of `Logger` above (add your usual logging configuration).

Comment: Hi @Vasfed,
Thanks but it is not working. Only logstash logs are written in "log/logstash_#{Rails.env}.log" file. "log/#{Rails.env}.log" file is empty.

Comment: @himanshugupta try running in a `config.after_initialize do ...` block